# Problemas para ordenar código com ShellSort

Tags: c, classificação

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
 int id_submissao;
 int tempo;
 int id_equipe;
 int id_problema;
 char status;
} Linha;

void shellSort(Linha *v, int n) {
 int i = (n - 1) / 2;
  int chave, k, aux;

  while(i != 0) {
   do {
     chave = 1;
     for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
        if(v[k] > v[k + i]){
           aux = v[k];
           v[k] = v[k + i];
           v[k + i] = aux;
           chave = 0;
        }
     }
  }while(chave == 0);
      i = i / 2;
  }
}

void imprimeLinhas (Linha* vet, int N) {
int i;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%d %d %c %d %d\n",
           vet[i].id_equipe,
           vet[i].id_problema,
           vet[i].status,
           vet[i].tempo,
           vet[i].id_submissao);

printf("\n");
}

int main () {

FILE* arq;
Linha vet[105];
int i;

arq = fopen("EDI-1S2018-Aula11-runs.txt", "r");

for (i = 0; !feof(arq); i++)
    fscanf(arq, "%d %d %d %d %c\n",
           &vet[i].id_submissao,
           &vet[i].tempo,
           &vet[i].id_equipe,
           &vet[i].id_problema,
           &vet[i].status);

printf("**********************************\n");
printf("**   Dados antes da ordenacao   **\n");
printf("**********************************\n");
imprimeLinhas (vet, 105);

shellSort(vet, 105);

printf("\n");
printf("**********************************\n");
printf("**    Dados apos a ordenacao    **\n");
printf("**********************************\n");
imprimeLinhas (vet, 105);

return 0;
}
```

[image: Erro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de ler um pouco sobre shell sort eu encontrei alguns problemas em seu código, como na maioria dos algorítimos de ordenação, os exemplos são dados com vetores de inteiros, mas observe que você tem um vetor de struct, logo, a comparação de v[i] > v[j], como qualquer outra comparação (==, <=, >=, !=) logica não iria funcionar dessa maneira visto que nós so podemos comparar tipos não primitivos em C, então a primeira coisa que eu fiz foi arrumar sua função de ordenar, de modo que ela compare os `vetor[k].tempo`  dessa forma ele consegue verificar os tempos maiores antes dos menor menores então podendo ordena-los. Perceba também que sua variável auxiliar não pode ser um inteiro uma vez que ela é usado para mover as estruturas dentro do seu vetor, teremos então que usar uma variável auxiliar do tipo `Linha`

```
void shellSort(Linha *v, int n) {
 int i = (n - 1) / 2;
 int chave, k;
 Linha aux;


 while(i != 0) {   do {
 chave = 1;
 for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
    if(v[k].tempo > v[k + i].tempo){
       aux = v[k];
       v[k] = v[k + i];
       v[k + i] = aux;
       chave = 0;
    }
 }
  }while(chave == 0);
    i = i / 2;
  }
}
```

Também Perceba que a sua função `imprimeLinhas(Linha vet,int N)` esta incorreta, de forma que ela espera receber uma unica struct do tipo Linha como parâmetro, mas você passa um vetor, como sabemos que você quer imprimir o vetor então temos que modificar seu escopo para: `imprimeLinhas(Linha *vet,int N)` dessa forma você tem a função esperando um vetor.

Perceba as diferenças entre implementação quando você usa um vetor de tipos primitivos, ou uma struc que contem varias informações.

Percebi também que você não trata os arquivos de forma correta, aconselho a você fazer o seguinte para abrir seu arquivo:

```
arq = fopen("EDI-1S2018-Aula11-runs.txt", "r");
if(arq == NULL) {
    perror("Erro ao abrir arquivo");
    return(-1);
}
```

Dessa forma você consegue assegurar que o arquivo foi aberto corretamente, caso contrario o seu programa encerra.Também assim que terminar de usar o arquivo é ideal fecha-lo, no seu caso depois de ler todo o arquivo você pode fechar o arquivo, desta forma:

```
fclose(arq);
```

Veja que o função `feof()` retorna um valor `não zero` se o arquivo não tiver chegado ao fim, e caso contrario, `valor zero`, perceba que essa não é uma boa maneira de assegurar que você leu seu arquivo todo já que a função percebe isso de acordo com a ultima operação de I/O (Você pode ler mais sobre isso na documentação [aqui](http://devdocs.io/c/io/feof)), e também não faz sentido já que seu vetor tem tamanho limita então a solução mais pratica seria deixar seu `for` da seguinte forma:

```
for (i = 0; i<105 i++)
```